# How to nest hamlet files?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm not familiar with Yesod and I'm facing some problems when nesting two hamlet files, one of them has a form.

```
loginForm :: Form Admin
loginForm = renderDivs $ Admin
    <$> areq textField (bfs ("Login" :: Text)) Nothing
    <*> areq passwordField (bfs ("Password" :: Text)) Nothing
```

Where `Form Admin` stands for `type Form a = Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult a, Widget)`, just a syntactic sugar to avoid repeating.

I'm using a helper function to call the hamlet file, whose is a footer and has the form, considering that, it'll appear in all pages.

```
footer widgetLogin enctypeLogin = toWidget $(hamletFile "hamlet/footer.hamlet")
```

I shrunk the `footer.hamlet` file to the sensitive data.

```
<form role="form" method="post" enctype=#{enctypeLogin} action=@{AdminRedirectR}>
    ^{widgetLogin}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go
```

Then, some of the pages that calls the footer function:

```
getIndexR :: Handler Html
getIndexR = do
    generateFormPost loginForm >>= \(widgetLogin, enctypeLogin) ->
        defaultLayout $(whamletFile "hamlet/index.hamlet")
```

Inside `index.hamlet` I'll have `^{footer}`, but doing so, it pops out an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type Page with actual type ‘HandlerSite m0’
The type variable m0 is ambiguous …
```

The type `Page` is an instance of the typeclass `Yesod`.

If I replace the `^{footer}` by the footer code itself, the error goes away, but it's kinda clumsy and not practical.

How can I fix that?

Comment: The message "the type variable m0 is ambiguous" suggests that you probably just need to put an explicit type signature in the right place. Beyond that, I don't know.

Comment: Actually, it's still trying to match `Page` with `HandlerSite`, so I think my comment is probably wrong.